# RuntimeError: The animation function must return a sequence of Artist objects

Tags: matplotlib, jquery-animate

I get the following error when trying to create an animation from contour plots

```
    def plot_sn2(X,Y,sn,ax,i,rwb):

      X1=np.linspace(-10,10,100)
      X2=np.linspace(-10,10,100)
      XX1,XX2=np.meshgrid(X1,X2)
      YY=np.zeros(XX1.shape)
      for i in range(X2.size):
        for j in range(X1.size):
          YY[i,j]=sn.sigmoid(sn.perceptronIN(np.asarray([X1[j],X2[i]]),list(rwb[i][0][0]),rwb[i][1][0]))
      ax.contourf(XX1,XX2,YY,cmap=my_cmap,alpha=0.6)
      ax.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],c=Y,cmap=my_cmap)
      ax.plot()

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
​
rwb=sn.rwb()
def animate(i):
  ax.clear()
  if(i==0):
    i+=1
  plot_sn2(X,Y,sn,ax,i,rwb)


interval = 2#in seconds     
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=1000, interval=200, blit=True)
HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
​
plt.show()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/**init**.py", line 215, in process
>       func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 999, in _start
>       self._init_draw()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1740, in _init_draw
>       self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1765, in _draw_frame
>       raise RuntimeError('The animation function must return a '
>   RuntimeError: The animation function must return a sequence of Artist objects.

The `plot_sn2` is used to form the contour plot and the rest of the code is for the animation itself.

Comment: Blitting will not help in your case, because (1) you clear the axes, (2) You create the animation as html5 video. Hence use `blit=False`. This will also automatically get rid of the error.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - Consider add this as an answer?  Definitely helped me, thanks!